# Send mail using mandrill

Tags: jquery, html, email, mandrill

Im trying to send a mail using mandrill but i have not receiving the mail, i have a successful message when the mail is sent.

I just want to send the tel value.

This is my code

```
    jQuery(function($)  
{
    $("#contact_form").submit(function()
    {
       // var email = $("#email").val(); // get email field value
        var tel =$("#enviar").val();
        //var name = $("#name").val(); // get name field value
        //var msg = $("#msg").val(); // get message field value
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-js/src/ae244a4d28f7f51327f6982005d4283d5f329b35/mandrill.js",
            data: {
                'key': 'apikey',
                'message': {
                    //'from_email': email,
                    //'from_name': name,
                    'from_tel':tel,

                    'subject': 'Website Contact Form',
                    'text': tel,
                    'to': [
                    {
                        'email': 'mail@gmail.com',
                        'name': 'Taimur K Naziri',
                        'type': 'to'
                    }]
                }
            }
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            alert('Your message has been sent. Thank you!');
            alert(tel) // show success message
           // $("#name").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
            $("#enviar").val('');
            //$("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
            //$("#msg").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
            alert('Error sending message.');
        });
        return false; // prevent page refresh
    });
});

<form name="contactform" method="post" id="contact_form">
<input id="enviar" type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="ESCRIBE TU # CELULAR" required /><br>
<button class="button" type="submit"> Gratis x 30 días </button><br>
</form>
```

Maybe is something wrong in the script but i don't know what is the possible mistake, there are any other way to sent mail using mandrill , javascript or jquery?

Comment: now i change the url for https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json but i still have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sending emails using the Mandrill API you need to change the URL:
to: https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json

```
function sendMail(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
    data: {
      'key': 'YOUR_KEY',
      'message': {
        'from_email': 'YOUR_SENDER@example.com',
        'to': [
          {
            'email': 'YOUR_RECEIVER@example.com',
            'name': 'YOUR_RECEIVER_NAME',
            'type': 'to'
          }
        ],
        'subject': 'title',
        'html': 'html can be used'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: i change the url but i still having the same problem

Comment: When you login to Mandrill. Can you check the log. Is there anything being triggered? Maybe Mandrill is sending the email, but it's getting caught by your spam filter?

Comment: I am using the same code, but stilll facing some issues, please help me to fix. I am getting the api logs and the response like this.      {
        "email": "yash71720@gmail.com",
        "status": "queued",
        "_id": "67288ffe88584cbabc0d7cc899bf22e3",
        "reject_reason": null
    }